# nLog missing log data

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

Sometime nLog is not logging all debug information (some of log.Debug... are missing in debug file), does anyone know why is this happening and how to avoid that?

Here is my nLog configuration

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <variable name="appTitle" value="Service"/>
  <targets async="true">
    <target name="fallbackDebug" xsi:type="FallbackGroup" returnToFirstOnSuccess="true">
      <target xsi:type="File" fileName="C:\Logs\${date:format=yyyyMMdd}_Debug.txt" layout="..."/>
      <target xsi:type="File" fileName="C:\Logs\${date:format=yyyyMMdd}_Debug_bu.txt" layout="..."/>
    </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" levels="Trace,Debug,Error,Fatal"       writeTo="fallbackDebug" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

In code I'm using following

```
private static Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
...
log.Debug("Some debug info");
```

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know that something is missing? Can you provide a small sample application that reproduces that problem?

Comment: I'm not able to provide small app that is reproducing that problem, because it is happening only in our system which is very big, and we're logging a lot of debug information in short time. I know that something is missing because for example, before creating an order in DB, I'm logging that action. If I take a look in DB, order is presented, but log which is corresponding to that action is not presented.

Comment: Sounds strange. You could add some simple logging that is independent of NLog at that specific place and see whether that works or not. If it doesn't work, it is not a problem with NLog but with your code which seems to execute some other code that inserts the order. If your simple logging works but NLog doesn't, you proved that NLog misses something.

Comment: I'll try that, but I'm sure something is wrong with nLog, because order creation is on one place in project and it is sequential with order creation: 
 writeLog();
 createOrder(); 
 ... So to be able to create order log must be executed. I'm not sure if async="true" causes problems? But in our case, async is mandatory :(

Comment: You could try switching async off, just to test whether it is causing this.

Comment: I know, but it is currently on production :) and I'm not able to run it on development :)

Comment: Any conclusions on this? I have the same problem, but without using the async flag, so that's not the issue. We are using it quite heavily, and are actually losing quite a number of log entries.

Comment: No conclusion on my side :) We gave up on that project and froze implementation :)

Answer (score 2):

You must call `LogManager.Flush()` method at the end.

**Example:**

```
private static Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
...
log.Debug("Some debug info");
...
LogManager.Flush();
```